# Limit Execution Time in Node

Tags: node.js, v8, node-modules

I am working on a node-based MUD game and I would like to limit the amount of time any one command can execute before it gets killed (e.g. 1000ms).  I found a module called Tripwire which seems promising but it does not appear to be actively maintained.  Tripwire does work as advertised.  It manages to force an exception if someone creates an endless loop, but it does not support any resumption of the original script thread.

I am looking for either:

(1) A similar but actively maintained Node module that can interrupt and resume the original event thread, or,

(2) A working example of V8's Isolate::IsExecutionTerminating + Isolate::CancelTerminateExecution (I forked Tripwire but I haven't done any meaningful C++ in a long time and am now just beating my head against the wall).

I have only been able to find test cases so far (which is at least something).  I am really hoping that someone has already tackled this, though.

Test cases:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/ad55afcb459dafda1cf48e676985717fd7eae786/test/cctest/test-thread-termination.cc

I know this is a bit vague.

Comment: launch a child process for each command, and inside a `setTimeout` kill that child process.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this that doesn't either run each command in a child process that you just kill if it runs too long or by modifying the internals of the V8 JS execution engine.  There's no provision at the Javascript level for something like this.  You could, of course, attempt to code this into the executing Javascript (where it checks itself to see if it's been running too long and bails if so), but I assume you were looking for something that worked automatically from the outside of the executing Javascript.

Comment: Unfortunately a child process wouldn't work in this situation.  Each command needs full access to the game's state.  I am trying to modify the V8 engine through native modules but yeah... rusty C++.  I was hoping someone else had done it first.

Comment: Instrumenting code as you suggested @jfriend00 might be my next path to investigate.  I am doing some parsing with acorn.  It wouldn't be too hard to inject something in there I guess (seems heavy-handed... but if it works).

Comment: FYI, you could put game state in redis and then access it from multiple processes.  I think using multiple processes will be the cleanest way of managing a timeout like you're trying to do and it will also allow your app to scale.  You may just want to have a set of worker processes and a work queue that hands work out to the next available process and implement the timeout in the queue management code.

Comment: Interesting!  I have been thinking about how to scale it to multiple processors and had not considered something like redis.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up instrumenting the script by passing it through acorn and generating my own final script.  I am hoping that the sandbox is locked down to prevent users from escaping it.  Example of "compiled" output:

```
createPermissions(expr) {
    let __mec = __bfc(this || GameMaster, 'public', 'createPermissions', __FILE__, false); try { let parts = expr.split('/');

    for (let i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        __ala(); let foo = parts.slice(0, i).join('/');
    } } finally { __efc(__mec, 'createPermissions'); }
}
```

This new "language" supports public, protected, package, and private variables/methods (by maintaining its own internal call stack, execution context, etc).  The directives are "reserved words" (e.g. __bfc=begin function call, __ala=assert loop alarm).

Thanks @jfriend00 for the suggestion.

For those who are curious: [Transpiler Module](https://github.com/kristianoye/kmud/blob/master/src/compiler/MudScriptTranspiler.js)